# Find the first six terms in a reduced coherent sequence defining $i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Find the first six terms in a reduced coherent sequence defining $i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

I need to use the sequence $a_k=2^{5^{k-1}}$ but not sure how to? Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is finding elements of order 4 modulo successively higher powers of 5.   To find an element of order 4 modulo a prime power $p^k$ (when one exists), you can find a primitive root modulo $p^k$ and then raise to the $\frac{\phi(p^k)}{4}$ power.  In this case, you should check:

1. 2 is a primitive root modulo every power $5^k$.  (This follows from the general result that if $r$ is a primitive root modulo an odd prime $p$, then either $r$ or $r+p$ is a primitive root modulo every power of $p$.)
2. $\phi(5^k) = 4 \cdot 5^{k-1}$.

From this, it follows that $2^{5^{k-1}}$ is an element of order $4$ modulo $5^k$.    So choose a large enough value for $k$, and you'll have an element whose residues modulo six consecutive powers of $5$ each have order $4$.  Hensel's lemma shows there are two elements of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5^{\times}$, and you will have found the residues of one of them modulo the first few powers of $5$.

Comment: Is 2,1,5,1,3,4  for the digits right?

Comment: There are different ways to represent an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a "sequence".  It sounds like you want to write elements in terms of "digits" $a_0 a_1 a_2 \cdots$ where the number you're representing is $a_0 + a_1 \cdot 5 + a_2 \cdot 5^2 \cdots$.  Except that we usually make digits between 0 and 4, and one of yours is 5.

Comment: I get $2$, $1$, $2$, $1$, $3$.